# How do I disable receiving calls and messages?

Tags: calls

I use my HTC Evo 3D (currently Android 2.3, soon Android 4.0) to record cycling workouts (GPS + Endomondo). During workouts, I don't want to receive any calls / messages for the following reasons:

- I don't want to be disturbed when relaxing
- I want to conserve the battery
- sometimes I listen to music and calls/messages interrupt the music, which I don't like, especially when the calls are business-related during my non-work time

How would I accomplish this? The flight mode doesn't allow GPS to be enabled, therefore this isn't a solution.

Comment: I use Endomondo as well (albeit with a HTC Desire, Android 2.2) and GPS still works even if Flight Mode is enabled. Of course, the map feature of Endomondo won't work if you do that (as it downloads the map tiles from the Internet), but who uses that whilst they're running...

Comment: Also, a fix for #1 and #3 would be to simply put your phone on silent. My music player (Spotify) isn't interrupted by messages/ emails/ calls if silent mode is enabled.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this:

- Airplane mode: You say that it doesn't allow GPS, but it does. You need to enable GPS when you're in airplane mode.
- Disable radio: In dialer enter `*#*#4636#*#*`
  Select phone info and pick turn off radio.
- Take out your SIM card. This one is only applicable if you have a GSM device.
- You can enable call forwarding in `Phone settings -> Call forwarding`.

If your only problem is that calls interrupt music than you can try using a music player allows you to set how audio focus changes are handled. One example is [Poweramp](http://powerampapp.com).

Answer (score 8):

I use Google Voice and only give out that number for calls and texts. It has a very nice "Do Not Disturb" feature.

Answer (score 5):

[Mr. Number](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mrnumber.blocker&hl=en) is an app that lets you set profiles based on volume profile (silent, vibrate, etc.) that allows you to block all call/texts for a given profile. When you're done, simply switch off that profile!

Also, as Richard mentioned, Airplane mode + GPS activated would be a wonderfully simple solution :)

Answer (score 4):

On my Nexus S with MIUI ROM I use Firewall: turn it on, select the "reject all calls" behaviour, and I'm set...